# Extracting values of upper triangle by row order

Tags: r, rows

I have the following matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)

> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

I would like to transform the upper triangle (without diagonal) to vector in the order of rows:
If I you this:

```
> mat1<-as.vector(mat[upper.tri(mat)])
> mat1
[1]  5  9 10 13 14 15
```

I would like to get the vector (mat1) by rows order as following: `5,9,13,10,14,15`

Comment: Some algebraic tricks and some obscure functions lend to this solution. `utMat <- upper.tri(mat); mat[utMat][rank(((row(mat) * utMat * nrow(mat)) + (col(mat) * utMat))[utMat])]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do a transpose and take the `lower.tri`

```
t(mat)[lower.tri(t(mat))]
#[1]  5  9 13 10 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too:

```
indices <- which(upper.tri(mat, diag=FALSE), arr.ind=TRUE)
mat[indices[order(indices[,1]),]]
# [1]  5  9 13 10 14 15
```

Comment: Few people are continuously down-voting me in many of my previous answers without explaining any reason that I don't understand too, thanks for noticing @Rich Scriven

Comment: I upvoted! Thanks a lot for your answer @SandipanDey!

Comment: Thank you very much @Avi